# Six Children and 3 Flavors of Ice Cream

Tags: combinatorics

$\textbf{Q}$ : There are $6$ children each offered a single scoop of any of $3$ flavors of ice cream. In how many ways can each child choose a flavor for their scoop so that some flavor of ice cream is selected by exactly $3$ children?

- I struggled with this for a bit. I'm counting this as $ 3 \cdot C(6,3) \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$ where $3$ is for the number of colors, $C(6,3)$ is choosing $3$ kids from $6$ to have one flavor and $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$ comes from the choices that the last $3$ children have.

I'm doing something wrong though as this is not correct. Could someone help point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: The rules are not clear...is $xxxyyy$ a good choice?  If so you need to take care not to double count those choices.

Comment: Hi. The post below added what was missing - "not 2 people have the same color". The problem was stated as given and it threw me off as well. With this addition, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be the way
@geometry fanatic the mistake you are making is that in the $2.2.1 $ allows the case where two children have the same flavour(other than the flavour assigned to the other $3$). This violates the constraint in the question.So the problem will be solved with the principle of exclusion. So it should be $(3.C(6,3).2.2.2)-6 = 474$. Subtracting $6$ removes the cases where we have two children having the same flavour(of the leftover $2$ flavour). So the other three left children will have the case where all three have same flavour.for eg if we have flavours $f_1 \space f_2 \space   and \space 
 f_3$ then $ f_1f_1f_1f_2f_2f_2$ will be a case. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: This makes sense outside of the explanation for the -6. I'll try to see what you mean by what's said. Thank you.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks. The wording on the problem was very unclear. I'm happy you were able to catch it. Makes sense that you want only 3 people to have the same - so exclude when 2 people have the same.

Comment: Glad that you got it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities that result in some flavor being chosen by exactly three children:

- three children choose one flavor, two choose another and one chooses the remaining one;
- three children choose one flavor and the other three choose a second flavor.

For the first case, the number of ways to divide up the children like this is $\binom 63\binom32=60$. Then we can assign the flavors to groups in $3!$ ways, giving a total of $360$ ways.

For the second case there are only $\binom 52$ ways to divide up the children into two groups of three, since it is equivalent to choosing two other children to be in the same group as child 1. Then we can assign the flavors to (child 1's group), (other group), (no-one) in $3!$ ways, giving another $60$ ways.

Therefore the answer is $420$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution by inclusion/exclusion.  I am assuming we want to count the number of distributions of ice cream to children in which *at least one* flavor is distributed to exactly three children.

The number of ways to distribute one flavor to exactly three children is
$$\binom{3}{1} \binom{6}{3} 2^3$$
But we have double-counted the cases where two flavors are each distributed to exactly three children.  There are
$$\binom{3}{2} \binom{6}{3}$$
such cases.  So correcting for double-counting, the answer is
$$\binom{3}{1} \binom{6}{3} 2^3 - \binom{3}{2} \binom{6}{3} = \boxed{420}$$